# python if $_GET is empty do something & url path

Tags: python, path, cgi

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

test = form['name'].value

if test is None:
    print('empty')
else:
    print ('Hello ' + test)
```

... and that doesn't seem to display anything when my url is something like .../1.py

if i set it to .../1.py?name=asd it will display  `Hello asd`

also how to get everything after the question mark and after the domain name: for example if i try to access `http://localhost/thisis/test` i want to get `/thisis/test`.

edit: i tried to use `try:` and i couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part of my question, i found what the problem is and that's the correct code:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

try:
    test = form['name'].value
except KeyError:
    print('not found')
else:
    print(test)
```

for my second question:

```
import os
print(os.environ["REQUEST_URI"])
```